# Подключение к базе в php 7.4 в нутри в function

Tags: php, функции, mysqli

такой вопрос есть задача перевести сайт с пхп 5.4 на 7.4 и все вроде сделал, все вроде работает кроме кода в function { }
Дело в том что тот кто писал скрипт, писал его на пхп 5, и понаписал сотни function { } внутри в которых делает запросы в базу, в 5 пхп все работает однако в 7 версии пхп внутри функции не работает соединение с базой, как я понял потому что функции изолированы, даже инклуд не работает я не могу даже заинклудить файл с подключением к БД, внутри в function { }, работает только единственный вариант если там внутри прописать наново соединение с базой.
Вопрос такой, существует ли способ как то подключить базу в нутри в function { } кроме как прописать там наново соединение, так как переписывать пол скрипта выносить это все за приделы функций я наверное сума сойду))). Спасибо на добром совете.

Comment: Знаете, звучит как-то пугающе про сотни функций с запросами к базе и про попытку заинклюдить файл с подключением к БД внутри функции. Что вы сделали в качестве перевода с PHP 5.4 на 7.4? Добились совместимости кода с новой версией, а код оставили функциональным и т.п.? Мне кажется это не совсем то, что подразумевалось. Конкретно про подключение к базе все же обычно делают отдельный класс для запросов к БД, часто это класс одиночка, чтобы не создавать более одного соединения. Может быть вы какой-то пример кода дадите, чтобы оценить масштаб проблемы?

Comment: Дмитрий, в нутри в функции внешнее соеденение которое за скобками функции не работает, как сделать так что бы заработало вот в чем суть вопроса, я еще учусь, был бы умнее не задавал бы таких вопросов, в хеадере сайта подключаюсь к БД так:

 $db_host = "localhost"; // сервер
 $db_user = ""; // имя пользователя
 $db_pass = ""; // пароль
 $db_name = ""; // название базы данных

 // выполнение подключения
 $db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die('Ошибка: подключение sql не выполнено.'); // сообщение об ошибке
 $db->set_charset('utf8');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тут вижу два варианта

передача соединения с базой данных в качестве параметра в функцию

```
function myFunction($db) {
  // использовать $db для выполнения запросов к базе данных
}

// создать соединение с базой данных
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

// вызвать функцию, передав соединение с базой данных в качестве параметра
myFunction($db);
```

Если у вас много функций, которые нуждаются в доступе к базе данных, вы можете создать класс, который будет обрабатывать подключение к базе данных, и передавать экземпляр этого класса

```
class Database {
  private $connection;

  public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database) {
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
  }

  public function query($sql) {
    return mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
  }
}

function myFunction(Database $db) {
  // использовать $db для выполнения запросов к базе данных
}

// создать экземпляр класса Database
$db = new Database("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

// вызвать функцию, передав экземпляр класса Database в качестве параметра
myFunction($db);
```

Comment: require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/moduls/db.php';
страно такое подключение сработало, однако через require_once не срабатывало подключение, не уверен что и это будет до конца и всегла срабатывать, я еще учусь, скажите а в чем разница и будет ли оно работать всегда или только в определенных моментах

Comment: @Игорь `require` включает указанный файл в текущий скрипт и, если файл не найден, он вызывает фатальную ошибку и останавливает выполнение скрипта. `require_once` делает то же самое, но только если файл не был ранее включен в текущий скрипт. Если файл уже был включен ранее, `require_once` игнорирует его.